# Bokeh linked brushing with custom index

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

Say I have a table with columns: id, x1, y1, x2, y2.
I want to plot x1 vs y1 and x2 vs y2 side by side, and have linked brushing by id. The Bokeh documentation on linked brushing [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/linking.html) only shows example when the two plots share one same axis.

How do I do this with Bokeh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same example, is this not what you want? each plot with a different x and y, but still linked?

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("brushing.html")

x = list(range(-20, 21))
x2 =list(range(-30, 10))
y0 = [abs(xx) for xx in x]
y1 = [xx**2 for xx in x2]

# create a column data source for the plots to share
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, x2=x2, y0=y0, y1=y1))

TOOLS = "box_select,lasso_select,help"

# create a new plot and add a renderer
left = figure(tools=TOOLS, width=300, height=300, title=None)
left.circle('x', 'y0', source=source)

# create another new plot and add a renderer
right = figure(tools=TOOLS, width=300, height=300, title=None)
right.circle('x2', 'y1', source=source)

p = gridplot([[left, right]])

show(p)
```